# How to use the condition in DB->select Laravel

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel

I wanna to filters columns who i gets from database.

I have a array like a:

```
$array = array('name', 'year', 'hobbies');
```

And a wanna get from db only column if its in array.
Like a this code but this code isn't work.

```
$query->select(
    if (in_array("name",$array)) {
      'name',
    }
    if (in_array("year",$array)) {
      'year',
    }
    if (in_array("hobbies",$array)) {
      'hobbies'
    }
  );
```

I cant do it after db query in foreach.

I will by very happy, if you give me a any idea or sollution.
Thanks

BTW: Sorry for bad english language.

Comment: very interesting question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can used `addSelect` function.

from this code:

```
$query->select(
    if (in_array("name",$array)) {
      'name',
    }
    if (in_array("year",$array)) {
      'year',
    }
    if (in_array("hobbies",$array)) {
      'hobbies'
    }
  );
```

should be:

```
   $query->select("id","foo","test"); // foo , test sample columns


   if (in_array("name",$array)) {
      $query->addSelect("name"); // or $query->addSelect(DB::raw("name"));
   }
   if (in_array("year",$array)) {
      $query->addSelect("year"); // or $query->addSelect(DB::raw("year"));
   }
   if (in_array("hobbies",$array)) {
      $query->addSelect("name"); // or $query->addSelect(DB::raw("hobbies"));
   }

 $query = $query->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use where in query builder.

Look this example.

```
$foo = DB::table('tableName')->where('Column', 'Value')->get();
```

Follow the example and you filter results, but if you want filter columns, you can take with the example

```
->select('name', 'email as user_email')
```

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Sorry, but it is not the solution of problem. I wanna filter who columns i get, no rows from column value. You posted a no useless solution. Thanks for your effort.